# Handing incoming calls - broadcast to multiple agents

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I have an application where I need to delay answering the incoming call while I ring multiple agents in parallel, and then connect the incoming call to one selected agent.  Note that for this application it is not an option to answer the call and play a MP3 that mimics a phone ringing - the calling system is an automated system that recognizes when the call has been answered and immediately looks for an agent to respond.

If I want to forward to a single agent's phone, `<Dial>` + `answerOnBridge` works perfectly.

I have not been able to come up with a solution for ringing multiple agents in parallel.  My issue is holding off the incoming call from being answered.  I've tried:

- Delay responding to incoming webhook while I locate an agent (Twilio times out)
- Respond to the incoming webhook with short duration `<Pause>` only.  Twilio re-sends the incoming webhook after the timeout (with a new CallSid which complicates things).  This might work (I can bridge the call on a later retry once I locate an agent), but unfortunately some carriers seem to not handle this `<Pause>` only - I see `Call Failed`.
- Respond to the incoming webhook with long duration `<Pause>` + `<Hangup>`.  Then when an agent answers, redirect the incoming call with `client.calls().update()`.  This fails with:

  > TwilioRestException: HTTP 400 error: Unable to update record: Call is not in-progress. Cannot redirect.

NOTE: the `update()` works if I respond in a way that answers the incoming call ... but that doesn't work for me.

Is there some other way to keep the incoming call ringing / truly not answered while I broadcast call a few agents, and then connect the incoming caller to one selected agent?  Conceptually I'd like something that does a `<Enqueue>` + `answerOnBridge`, but I'm running out of ideas for how this can be done...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Have you tried using multiple [`<Number>`s](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/number) within your original `<Dial answerOnBridge="true">`? That would dial each number until one is picked up, connecting the agent who answered and cancelling the other calls.

Something like:

```
<Response>
  <Dial answerOnBridge="true">
    <Number>FIRST_NUMBER</Number>
    <Number>SECOND_NUMBER</Number>
  </Dial>
</Response>
```

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Hi Phil - I have not.  That sounds like it might be a good option, thanks.  I've toyed with a few different options for how the forwarding works ... one is where I use <Gather> to require the agents to ACK the incoming call (to prevent the caller from getting their voicemail.  If I wanted to go down that road, is there any option for that?

Comment: Also, is there any way to provide a unique delay for each <Number>?  For instance, what if I want to have FIRST_NUMBER ring right away, and then have SECOND_NUMBER start ringing, say, 5 seconds later?  (to give FIRST_NUMBER a head start / opportunity to grab the caller first)

Comment: and it just occurred to me that I need to know which number "wins" (answers first and is connected to the incoming call).  I imagine there's some way to get that info via a call status callback?

Comment: Did some testing.  The incoming call keeps ringing while it is broadcast to the agent numbers - great!  I then attempted to add a `url` to each number, and then present a `<Gather>` challenge to each agent to confirm it's a live person.  When I added the `url`, as soon as the first agent answers it disconnects all other agent calls.  So basically this approach works, but suffers from the "agent's voicemail picks up early" problem alluded to in the docs.  Is there any way to defer the agent "selection" on the twilio end until after I confirm it's a live person (via `<Gather>`)?

Comment: Ah, ok. No that is still a problem with this approach. The alternative is that you generate all the calls yourself using the API. That gives you all the control over those calls, including delaying them, but brings you back to the issue with having to have the call continue to ring while waiting for someone to answer. I can't think of a way to do that and handle an agent's voicemail answering.

Comment: darn.  so close but yet ....  Consider this an enhancement request @philnash.  It would be great if the `<Dial>` verb had an option to delay the connection to the called number(s) until the `url` returned some affirmative response.  Perhaps a new `<Connect>` noun like `<Connect><Incoming></Connect>` or something to that effect that allows you to filter out answers to the `<Number>`s before making the connection.  How hard could that be?  :-)